# Assumptions for stochastic Fubini's theorem for Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, order-of-integration

I am looking for a basic statement of stochastic Fubini's theorem for Brownian Motion and simple integrands. I have been searching in the internet but I have only been able to find references which are overly academic in nature.

The setup is a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ where $\mathscr{F}=(\mathscr{F}_t:t \in \mathbb{R}^+)=\sigma(W_t: t \in \mathbb{R}^+)$ is the filtration generated by a Brownian Motion $(W_t: t \in \mathbb{R}^+)$.

*We now consider:*

1. *A generic process $F(u,v) \equiv F(u,v,\omega)$, and*
2. *A deterministic function $f(u,v)$,*

*where $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\omega \in \Omega$.*

**Q.1) Under what conditions can we invert the order of integration for a stochastic integrand:**
$$\int_0^{t_1}\left(\int_0^{t_2}F(u,v)\text{d}W_u\right)\text{d}v=\int_0^{t_2}\left(\int_0^{t_1}F(u,v)\text{d}v\right)\text{d}W_u \ \ ?$$

**Q.2) Under what conditions can we invert the order of integration for a deterministic integrand:**
$$\int_0^{t_1}\left(\int_0^{t_2}f(u,v)\text{d}W_u\right)\text{d}v=\int_0^{t_2}\left(\int_0^{t_1}f(u,v)\text{d}v\right)\text{d}W_u \ \ ?$$

**Q.3) Is there any difference w.r.t. to the answer to Q.1 and Q.2 above if $F$ or $f$ only depend on one variable, either $u$ or $v$?**

The conditions might be on $F(u,v)$, $f(u,v)$, $t_1$, $t_2$ (e.g. adaptedness w.r.t to $\mathscr{F}$, boundness, etc.).

Any ***non-academic oriented*** reference is greatly appreciated; any explicit answer to the questions is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the references in the paper of Veraar? It must be in one of the textbooks there.

Comment: @Calculon from the references in Veraar I have access to Protter and Karatzas & Shreve. Protter gives a result which is very general and I have not found this result in Karatzas & Shreve (and, honestly, if there could be a reference a bit less technical than those two I would appreciate...).

Comment: I couldn't find it in Kallenberg either unfortunately but Karatzas and Shreve give it as an exercise (Problem 6.12). So at least you have the statement but the proof you will have to work on yourself (or ask here).

Comment: Thank you @Calculon I missed that, if I not mistaken it corresponds to the specific case: $F(u,v)=h(v)1_{\{u \leq W_u < \infty\}}$ for some continuous function $h(\cdot)$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$ with compact support.

Comment: You are welcome. A small error in your representation: It needs to be $h(v) 1_{v <W_u < \infty }$. The lower bound in the indicator function is $v$, not $u$.

Comment: Indeed thanks @Calculon